# CSS: использование css для анимации изменения внешнего вида блоков в виде стрелок (и не только)

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation, position

Добрый день

Помогите с некоторыми модификациями css для требуемого функционала:

Сделал следующий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/4qkxs7a1/1/

```
.ib-outline {
    width:                      calc(100% - 2 * 10px /*h-borders*/ - 2 * 10px /*h-margins*/);
    max-width:                  500px;

    margin:                     0px 10px 15px 10px;

    border:                     0px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow:                 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        -moz-box-shadow:            0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        -webkit-box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.ib-storage {   
    position:                   relative;

    width:                      100%;

    background:                 #ffffff;
}

.ib-storage-title {
    display:                    inline-block;
    vertical-align:             top;

    position:                   relative;

    width:                      calc(100% - 100px - (2 * 2px) - (25px + 10px));
    height:                     50px;
    line-height:                50px;

    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px 10px 0px 25px;

    text-align:                 left;

    font-family:                Verdana;
    font-size:                  20px;

    border:                     2px solid #0090d0;
    border-right:               1px solid #0090d0;

    background:                 #ffffff;

    cursor:                     pointer;
}

.ib-storage-title:before,
.ib-storage-title:after {
    content:                    '';

    position:                   absolute;

    width:                      0px;
    height:                     0px;
}

.ib-storage-title:before {
    top:                        -2px;
    right:                      -16px;

    border-bottom:              27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 27px solid transparent;
    border-left:                15px solid #0090d0;
}

.ib-storage-title:after {
    top:                        0px;
    right:                      -14px;

    border-bottom:              25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 25px solid transparent;
    border-left:                14px solid #ffffff;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover {
    border:                     2px solid #0090d0;
    border-right:               2px solid #0090d0;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover:before {
    top:                        calc(100% + 1px);
    left:                       calc(50% - 27px);

    border-left:                27px solid transparent;
    border-right:               27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 15px solid #0090d0; 
}

.ib-storage-title:hover:after {
    top:                        calc(100% - 1px + 1px);
    left:                       calc(50% - 27px + 2px);

    border-left:                25px solid transparent;
    border-right:               25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 14px solid #ffffff; 
}

.ib-content {
    display:                    inline-block;
    vertical-align:             top;

    width:                      calc(100px - 2 * 2px - 2 * 2px);
    height:                     50px;
    line-height:                50px;

    border:                     2px solid red;
    border-right:               1px solid red;

    background:                 #ffffff;
}

.ib-content:before,
.ib-content:after {
    content:                    '';

    position:                   absolute;

    width:                      0px;
    height:                     0px;
}

.ib-content:before {
    top:                        0px;
    right:                      -13px;

    border-bottom:              27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 27px solid transparent;
    border-left:                15px solid red;
}

.ib-content:after {
    top:                        2px;
    right:                      -11px;

    border-bottom:              25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 25px solid transparent;
    border-left:                14px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Есть блок (ib-outline), содержащий еще один блок (ib-storage), внутри которого содержится 2 блока (ib-storage-title и ib-content) (такое вложение сделано для совместимости со старыми браузерами, которые не поддерживали корректно outline свойство)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="ib-outline">
    <div class="ib-storage">
        <div class="ib-storage-title">ЗАГОЛОВОК ТЕМЫ</div>
        <div class="ib-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я хочу так реализовать css, чтобы было (см. jsfidder):

1) 2 прямоугольника и у каждого справа стрелочка/уголок, смотрящая справа

Реализовал, то второй блок (ib-content) не вплотную придвинулся к первому блоку (ib-storage-title), и не могу понять почему это произошло, выравнивать через абсолютное позиционирование - не самый лучший способ и хотелось бы автоматическое решение (вроде как использование `display: inline-block` должно было бы помочь, но не помогло)

2) при наведении на первый блок стрелочка вправо меняется на стрелочку вниз

Релизовано

**ПОШЛИ ВОПРОСЫ**

3) Как исправить ошибку, что когда наводишь мышкой на правую стрелочку блока `ib-storage-title`, то стрелочка исчезает и появляется нижняя стрелочка и тут же возвращается всё назад, в итоге появляется очень противное мигание?

Я понимаю причину - меняется состояние "есть объект / нет объекта / есть объект", но как это исправить, например, как задать в css, что наведение на стрелочку (объекты `:before` и `:after`) не должно восприниматься, как наведение на основной объект `ib-storage-title`.

4) Как можно задать эффект, что при наведении на объект `ib-storage-title` сначала исчезает правая стрелочка (втягивается в объект, т.е. в

```
border-left:                15px solid #0090d0;
```

15px уменьшаются до 0px, а потом вылезает нижняя стрелочка, т.е. в

```
border-top:                 15px solid #0090d0;
```

0px увеличивается до 15px?

Свойство `transtition` не помогло - выдаёт дичь вместо нужного эффекта.

5) для родительского блока `ib-outline` добавлена тень, а можно ли её сделать для стрелочек/уголков?

Когда я пытаюсь вставить код тени, то тень появляется вокруг прямоугольника, в который вписан уголок, что понятно, но можно ли как-то обойти это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить некоторые проблемы:

https://jsfiddle.net/3dtp5tyx/

1) для устранения мигания при наведении на элементы `.ib-storage-title:before`, `.ib-storage-title:after` (потому что эти элементы перемещаются в другое место и в следствии чего сразу перемещаются обратно) отключил обработчик `:hover` на этих элементах через свойство `pointer-events: none;`, а для hover элементов включил его обратно `pointer-events: auto;`

2) плавную анимацию вытягивания правого элемента реализовал через отслеживания изменения ширины элемента (поскольку к ширине все и привязано) через свойство `transition: width 0.1s;`

3) исключить из html кода учитывание перевода строки (\r\n), чтобы 2 элемента `.ib-storage-title` и `.ib-content` могли стоять вместе без какого либо перевода строки, т.е. вместо `<div></div><div></div>`, можно было бы использовать так `<div></div>\r\n<div></div>` -удалось избавиться через свойство `font-size: 0px;`

Возможно сработало, потому что позиционирование сделал более аккуратно, раньше не получалось.

**Что пока не удалось исправить**

1) анимация возникновения уголка в левом блоке, чтобы он плавно убирался из одной стороны и выдвигался в другой (последовательно)

Как понимаю, это легко было бы сделать, если бы уголок не менял своей позиции, но для двух уголков (сбоку и снизу) надо тогда использовать еще один элемент `<div>` которого нет или внедрять в `.ib-storage-title` какой-нибудь `<span>` или использовать `.ib-storage`, но это не совсем уместно

**Сам код:**

```
.ib-outline {
    width:                      calc(100% - 2 * 10px /*h-borders*/ - 2 * 10px /*h-margins*/);
    max-width:                  400px;

    margin:                     0px 10px 15px 10px;

    _border:                        0px solid #ffffff;
/*  box-shadow:                 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        -moz-box-shadow:            0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        -webkit-box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);*/
}

.ib-storage {
    position:                   relative;

    width:                      100%;

    background:                 #ffffff;

    font-size:                  0px;
}

.ib-storage-title,
.ib-content {
    cursor:                     pointer;

    display:                    inline-block;
    vertical-align:             top;

    position:                   relative;

    height:                     50px;
    line-height:                50px;

    margin:                     0px;

    background:                 #ffffff;    
}

.ib-storage-title {
    width:                      calc(100% - 100px - (1px + 2px) - (25px + 10px));

    padding:                    0px 10px 0px 25px;

    border:                     2px solid #409280;
    border-right-width:         1px;

    text-align:                 left;

    font-family:                Verdana;
    font-size:                  20px;   
}

.ib-storage-title:before,
.ib-storage-title:after {
    content:                    '';

    position:                   absolute;
    z-index:                    2;

    width:                      0px;
    height:                     0px;

    border:                     0px solid transparent;

    pointer-events:             none;
}

.ib-storage-title:before {
    top:                        -2px;
    right:                      -16px;

    border-bottom:              27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 27px solid transparent;
    border-left:                15px solid #409280;
}

.ib-storage-title:after {
    top:                        0px;
    right:                      -14px;

    border-bottom:              25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 25px solid transparent;
    border-left:                14px solid #ffffff;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover {
    width:                      calc(100% - 100px - (2px + 2px) - (25px + 10px));

    border:                     2px solid #409280;
    border-right:               2px solid #409280;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover:before,
.ib-storage-title:hover:after {
    border:                     0px solid transparent;

    pointer-events:             auto;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover:before {
    top:                        calc(100% + 1px);
    left:                       calc(50% - 27px);

    border-left:                27px solid transparent;
    border-right:               27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 15px solid #409280;
}

.ib-storage-title:hover:after {
    top:                        calc(100% - 1px + 1px);
    left:                       calc(50% - 27px + 2px);

    border-left:                25px solid transparent;
    border-right:               25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 14px solid #ffffff;
}

.ib-content {
    width:                      calc(100px - (1px + 0px) - 15px - 5px);

    border:                     2px solid #0090d0;
    border-left:                0px;
    border-right-width:         1px;

    transition:                 width 0.1s;
}

.ib-content:before,
.ib-content:after {
    content:                    '';

    position:                   absolute;

    width:                      0px;
    height:                     0px;
}

.ib-content:before {
    top:                        -2px;
    right:                      -16px;

    border-bottom:              27px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 27px solid transparent;
    border-left:                15px solid #0090d0;
}

.ib-content:after {
    top:                        0px;
    right:                      -14px;

    border-bottom:              25px solid transparent;
    border-top:                 25px solid transparent;
    border-left:                14px solid #ffffff;
}

.ib-content:hover {
    width:                      calc(100px - (1px + 0px) - 15px - 0px);
}
```